# Working CSS does not apply to element when using different selectors?

Tags: html, css, sass, wysihtml5

I am working on fixing an issue I am seeing with a `textarea` and `wysihtml`.

Currently I have something like this

```
<textarea class="wysihtml wysi-fix" required></textarea>
```

I have some CSS that looks like this

```
.wysi-fix{
 //some css here
}
```

The .wysi-fix CSS works on the textarea, however if I change the textarea to...

```
<textarea class="wysihtml" required></textarea>
```

and I change the CSS to

```
.wysihtml[required]{
 //the css goes here
}
```

The CSS no longer works, even though both selectors are selecting the same element on the HTML page. If it helps, I am using SASS instead of vanilla CSS. Any idea as to what is going on?

Comment: .wysihtml[required=required]{
 //the css goes here
}

Comment: and make the textarea required="required"

Comment: Also, is it not `.wysihtml:required {} `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), your attribute selector should work.

Possibly you have to use `[required="required"]` as attribute selector with a markup like `<textarea class="wysihtml" required="required"></textarea>`:

```
.wysihtml[required="required"]{
  //the css goes here
}
```

But a better way would be to use the [`:required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:required) pseudo class:

```
.wysihtml:required{
  //the css goes here
}
```

Comment: Is it required to have a value for `required`? I believe `.class[attr]` should work to recognise the attribute regardless of value, right?

Comment: Good point, it's not required as far as I know... my answer was more of a suggestion to a possible solution than an explanation, why `.wysihtml[required]` isn't working...

Comment: Is the `.wysihtml[required="required]` css a safer option for older browsers? The pseudoselector is CSS 3.0 correct?

Comment: It's not really a safer option. The `required` attribute came with HTML5, it's just for conformity with XHTML (In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the required attribute must be defined as `<select required="required" />`).  Yes `:required` is CSS3.

Answer (score 2):

Try `.wysihtml:required` instead of `.wysihtml[required]`